# How to deal with a very long process in TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity

We want to introduce new tests that will be driven from TeamCity. The build part itself is reasonably fast but we expect the processes that follow to take a **very** long time (hours to days). A different machine will produce results and the results will be analysed. And of course we want to see the results at the end in TeamCity.

While we fully expect the long runtimes, we don't want to keep our TC server occupied for hours or days while it's waiting for the final results.

We see several basic options:

- estimate the runtime and run a follow-up test at a predetermined time period
- keep checking at regular intervals
- run another build manually when the initial run is complete

How do you deal with a situation like this? What kind of considerations need to be taken into account? Did you try something like this and did it work (or not)?

Comment: What can it be doing for days? Other things could go wrong like a power failure, out of memory. Can you not break the tests into chunks? TeamCity works by having an allocated agent for the duration of the build

Comment: Running, exporting results and analysing those results... yes, it takes that long. I know short tests are preferable but sometimes you need an end-to-end test - hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your three listed options sound reasonable but you are missing important features of teamcity that are at your disposal.

An alternative:

1. Set up a build that will run **ONLY** the very long process. Lets call it the *Long_Build*
2. Have a second build which does the analysis depend on the success of the *Long_Build*. Lest's call this one the *Analysis_Build*
3. Setup an Agent capable of running the *Long_Build* and Teamcity will run the build only on that agent.
4. Have your QA build, or main build, or whatever build succeed IFF (if and only if) the *Analysis_Build* checks out. This build specifically is an information gathering build that will likely check all of your others tests and everything that your QA deployment depends on in order to call a changeset or set of changesets good enough for deployment.

My advice is to never run builds manually. Whatever criteria you would use to run a build manually can be scripted and run automatically. This way you are closer to a continuous integration process where you can guarantee quality.

Also, if you are not already doing it, make sure you label your source control with successful builds. Whether it is your *Long_Build*, *Analysis_Build* or *QA build* you should have a way to obtain successful builds that have passed a series of quality specs.